# Informix SQL 11.5 Attach the result of one select to another select by columns

Tags: sql, select, informix

i have one select:

```
select c1,c2,c3 from table1 where cond1

--result:

  a  b  c
  d  e  f
  g  h  i
```

and another select is

select m2  from table2 where cond2

```
--result:

 x
 y
 z
```

What combination of the two can I achieve with this output?

```
select m2 from table2 where cond2 **COMBIN**  select c1,c2,c3 from table1 where cond1

--result

x  a  b  c
y  d  e  f
z  d  e  f
```

of course, union and join didn't as COMBIN work.

Comment: I suppose you want to have the first  with the first, the second with the second, and the third with the third row. Now that won't be possible. Database table rows are not ordered; the select, normally , won't guarantee that the rows come in the same order in two identical query. You need an ordering column on both sides

Comment: @marcothesane :Is there a solution if we ignore ordering?

Comment: just add a common column to both tables and join them through that column:
select t2.c1, t1.c1,t1.c2,t1.c3 from t1,t2 where t1.common=t2.common;

Comment: @jsagrera there is no common column between tables

Comment: then I doubt you can do it in a single SQL statement. You could do it with a function/procedure fetching from both tables and return just joined row at a time

Comment: @jsagrera  T_H_A_N_K_S ,However, your solution was a good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with an SPL/Function.
Something like:

```
--drop procedure p1 ();
create procedure p1 () returning char AS t2_c1,char AS t1_c1,char AS t1_c2,char AS t1_c3;

   define t1_c1 char;
   define t1_c2 char;
   define t1_c3 char;  
   define t2_c1 char;
      
   prepare t1_id from "select c1,c2,c3 from t1";
   prepare t2_id from "select c1 from t2";
   declare t1_cur cursor for t1_id;
   declare t2_cur cursor for t2_id;
   open t1_cur;
   open t2_cur;
   
   while (1=1)   
    fetch t1_cur into t1_c1,t1_c2,t1_c3; 
    if (sqlcode == 100)  then
           exit;
    end if 
    fetch t2_cur into t2_c1; 
    if (sqlcode == 100)  then
           exit;
    end if      
    return t2_c1,t1_c1,t1_c2,t1_c3 with resume;    
   end while   

   close t1_cur;   
   close t2_cur;
   free t1_cur ;   
   free t2_cur ;
   free t1_id ;
   free t2_id ;
end procedure;

execute procedure p1();
```

Which should give you:

```
D:\Infx\ids1410>dbaccess stores7 p
Database selected.
Routine dropped.
Routine created.

t2_c1 t1_c1 t1_c2 t1_c3

x     a     b     c
y     d     e     f
z     g     h     i

3 row(s) retrieved.
Database closed.
D:\Infx\ids1410>
```

but it would be a lot simpler if you have a common column ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well - let's handcraft a common column, using the `ROW_NUMBER()` OLAP function, and join by that ...

```
WITH
-- your input
table1(c1,c2,c3) AS (
          SELECT 'a','b','c'
UNION ALL SELECT 'd','e','f'
UNION ALL SELECT 'g','h','i'
)
,
-- your input
table2(m2) AS (
          SELECT 'x'
UNION ALL SELECT 'y'
UNION ALL SELECT 'z'
)
-- real query starts here, replace "," with "WITH"
,
tb1_w_id AS (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c1) AS id
  , *
  FROM table1
  WHERE true
)
,
tb2_w_id AS (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY m2) AS id
  , *
  FROM table2
  WHERE true
)
SELECT
  m2
, c1
, c2
, c3
FROM tb1_w_id
JOIN tb2_w_id ON tb1_w_id.id = tb2_w_id.id
;
-- out  m2 | c1 | c2 | c3 
-- out ----+----+----+----
-- out  x  | a  | b  | c
-- out  y  | d  | e  | f
-- out  z  | g  | h  | i
```

Comment: As originally noted on another answer that suggested using the OLAP functions like ROW_NUMBER, Informix 11.50 (which hasn’t been supported for some time) does not support the OLAP (windowing) functions. Version 11.70 goes out of support at the end of September 2020 too. Versions 11.70, 12.10 and 14.10 do support the windowing functions, IIRC.  I agree that if the version of Informix supported the notation, it would be a way to achieve the result.